# How to stop printing when the value is None?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I am trying to print a list of ingredients and the amount required for a recipe, but there could be anywhere from 1 ingredient to 15 from a list of random recipes. I want to account for them all, but I don't want the ingredients of the measurements to print if the value is None.

An example of what I am pulling from:

'strIngredient1': 'Coffee', 'strIngredient2': 'Grain alcohol', 'strIngredient3': None, 'strIngredient4': None

I was trying to say, if strIngredient equals None, pass, else print the ingredient and the measurement, but everything I try will continue to print None.

```
if "strIngredient1" == '':
        pass
    else:
        print(f"{df2['strIngredient1'][x]} {df2['strMeasure1'][x]}")
```

For example, but I don't want the `None None` to print:

```
Drink name: Zorro
Sambuca 2 cl 
Baileys irish cream 2 cl 
White Creme de Menthe 2 cl 
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
```

Answer (score 3):

So few things here:

- You need to make sure you're indented properly as the else is not correct
- You're checking for an empty string and not `None`
- You're checking a string of `strIngredient1` against an empty string which logically will never be `True`

You could try something like this:

```
if df2['strIngredient1'][x] is None:
    pass
else:
    print(f"{df2['strIngredient1'][x]} {df2['strMeasure1'][x]}")
```

This should pass through assuming the value in `df2['strIngredient1'][x]` is `None`.

Please refer to this to understand string comparison: https://flexiple.com/python-string-comparison/

##### Alternative Output

If this option is required, it checks for both `strIngredient1` and `strMeasure1` to be `None` to skip. Otherwise if one of them is not `None`, it prints both ingredient and measure.

```
if (df2['strIngredient1'][x] is None) and (df2['strMeasure1'][x] is None):
    pass
else:
    print(f"{df2['strIngredient1'][x]} {df2['strMeasure1'][x]}")
```

Comment: Thank you!! I have one more question you might be able to help me with. If there is an ingredient and no measurement, I want to stop it from printing None but still print the ingredient. For example, Salt None should just be Salt. I want the ingredient and measurement to be on the same line, so I printed them together. I wonder if there is a way to say don't print anything is df2['strMeasure#'][x] is none?

Comment: See Additional Output section in answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your condition has `strIngredient1` between quotes so its checking if the string `strIngredient1` matches an empty string (which will always output `False`, hence it always goes to the `else` block).

so your conditions needs to check if

```
df2['strIngredient1'][x] == None
```